# Газетная утка. Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли слово "утка" (газетная) заключать в кавычки?

Предложение: *Это снова утка или правда?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...нужно ли слово "утка" (в значении газетная) заключать в кавычки?

Кавычки не нужны.

См. примеры [**в Большом толковом словаре:**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&all=x)

> **УТКА**
>
> <…>
>
> 3. Разг. Ложный сенсационный слух. *Газетная **у.** Пустить **утку** насчёт свадьбы. Распространять **утки** про кого-л. Не надо верить
>      всем **уткам**.*